# Find curvature and torsion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

If I have a regular curve such that $\boldsymbol{r}(s)=\boldsymbol{n}(s)$ for all $s$, how can i find curvature and torsion?

It is easy to see that $\|\boldsymbol{r}(s)\|=1$. Therefore, the trace of the curve is over a unitary sphere, but i can't find curvature and torsion. It is possible to find it?

Comment: What is $n(s)$ ?

Comment: It is the unitary normal vector to the curve: $n(s)=\frac{\ddot{r}(s)}{\|\ddot{r}(s)\|}$

Comment: @coffeemath: It's the principal normal of the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**:

As always, assume an arclength parametrization (so $s$ is arclength) and differentiate and see what the Frenet formulas tell you. Remember to use the fact that $\mathbf t,\mathbf n,\mathbf b$ give a basis. This is almost always the right approach when working with curves ...

Comment: Since $\dot{n}=t$, therefore $(1+\kappa)t=\tau b$, so $0=\tau$. Moreover, $t=-\kappa t$, so $\kappa=-1$. Is that correct?

Comment: Of course, $\kappa\ge 0$, so we have a problem. Constant curvature and $0$ torsion is a circle, and of course $\mathbf r = -\mathbf n$.

Comment: Oh... it depends on the book. For example, Differential Geometry of M.Lipschutz uses signed curvature.

Comment: Signed curvature only makes sense for a plane curve, and then $\mathbf n$ is defined differently. (By the way, I've written a differential geometry text, too.)

Comment: You are correct: Since $\kappa=-1$ and $\tau=0$, we can solve thFrenet-Serret equations and obtain $r(s)=(\sin(s),cos(s),0)$. But therefore $r(s)\neq n(s)$. It is probably a typo error.